# How to Buy a Pinion C1.6 Gearbox online

Tags: pinion

I'd like to assemble a bike base on Pinion gearbox, but I can't find it in the web shops.

Pinion [official website](https://pinion.eu/en/dealer-overview/) has list of dealers only.
I checked many of them, but can't find the way to buy only gearbox itself.
I got to the conclusion that I can buy a full bike with pinion gear box from dealers only.
I found only on online shop, but from the USA. https://www.bikeman.com/PIN-C16.html

How to online buy a Pinion C1.6 Gearbox in EU?

Comment: Can we have a little more context? Do you already have a frame that is compatible with the gearbox? Are you looking to build a gearbox-based bike from parts?

Comment: My plan is to customize/re-weld a frame from an old cheap bike. Yes, I am going to build bike from parts.

Comment: Well, good luck. This probably one of the most difficult DIY frame mods I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the shop

Price:  649,00 €

https://www.bullitt-bike.de/pinion-bullitt/pinion-c-linie-getriebe.html

[image]